# How NAT is able to change port numbers?

Tags: networking, tcp, router, nat

Based on my knowledge , I believe following statements are true.

1. Router can only redirect packet and can interact upto network(internet layer) only.
2. NAT maps the private ip to public ip. It uses a NAT table in which source private ip is mapped to public ip and also source port is changed with new source port.

My question is regarding NAT function for port . How NAT , that works in router can change something that relates to transport layer(port)?
i.e when the private system sends the source port , how NAT is able to change it with new port before sending it to internet.

I am missing something or maybe I am wrong somewhere . Would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

NATs intercept outgoing IP packets (including UDP and TCP) from nodes on the NAT's internal network and can modify the source IP and source port in the UDP and TCP header in place.  It will update other fields in the header as well (i.e. checksum).

Similarly, for incoming packets, the NAT will change the destination IP/port after finding an entry in its port mapping table that was created from a previous outbound packet or connection.

As to "how" - it just does.  It literally reconstructs a new UDP/TCP/IP header using the exact same payload of what it received.  The NAT is registered as the gateway device on the LAN, so all packets bound for the internet will be sent to the NAT's MAC address - if what you are wondering is how the NAT captures the packets to begin with.

Comment: so , does router that has NAT can read the transport layer data/headers ? Even though , the routers are network layer device and generally can read upto network layer only .

Comment: Yes - the NAT/Router will modify anything on the ethernet/wifi, IP, UDP and TCP header as needed. This includes IP, port, etc... in order to distinquish new connections from existing connections, the NAT will also look at the SYN bit on the TCP header.